# Guard throwing errors? (Listen gem)

Tags: ruby, guard, listen

i installed Guard and some other plugins for it. Whenever i try to run it, i just get a bunch of errors. I don't know Ruby at all so i really don't know the problem..it says all the listeners are listening, but i get a bunch of ruby errors.
Here are the errors:

C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': c
annot load such file -- wdm (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in`
require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.2.2/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:207:in `load_dependent_adapter'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.2.2/lib/listen/adapter
s/windows.rb:33:in`load_dependent_adapter'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.2.2/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:198:in `usable?'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.2.2/lib/listen/adapter
s/windows.rb:25:in`usable?'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.2.2/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:190:in `usable_and_works?'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.2.2/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:57:in`block in select_and_initialize'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.2.2/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:55:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.2.2/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:55:in`select_and_initialize'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.2.2/lib/listen/listene
r.rb:288:in `initialize_adapter'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.2.2/lib/listen/listene
r.rb:280:in`setup'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.2.2/lib/listen/listene
r.rb:52:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-1.8.1/lib/guard.rb:194:in`
block in start'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-1.8.1/lib/guard.rb:368:in
 `block in within_preserved_state'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-1.8.1/lib/guard.rb:365:in`
synchronize'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-1.8.1/lib/guard.rb:365:in
 `within_preserved_state'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-1.8.1/lib/guard.rb:190:in`
start'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-1.8.1/lib/guard/cli.rb:11
0:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb
:27:in`run'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation
.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor.rb:363:in`
dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:43
9:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-1.8.1/bin/guard:6:in`'
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/guard:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/guard:23:in`'

What's happening and how do i fix it?

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Frustrating!

Comment: This [SO answer][1] should be able to answer your question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279471/missing-dependencies-in-compass-sass/19306476#19306476

Comment: did you use bundle  to install?